# why isnt the player appearing on the JFrame?

Tags: java

**I have this code:**

```
public Juego() {
    setFocusable(true);

    loop = new Timer(10, this);
    loop.start();

    jugador = new Jugador(400, 400);
}

public void pintar(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    jugador.dibujar(g2D);
}
```

that is supposed to draw the player into the screen, and this is the code for the actual player:

```
public class Jugador extends PosicionGlobal {

private String imagendejugador = "/imagenes/jugador.png";

public Jugador(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}

public void actualizar() {

}

public void dibujar(Graphics2D g2D) {
    g2D.drawImage(imagendejugador(), x, y, null);

}

public Image imagendejugador(){
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagendejugador));
    return icono.getImage();
}
}
```

When I run it the player doesn't appear its just the same white screen as before. PD: I do have a `JFrame` and I already add this class to it.

**In case its is needed here is the PosicionGlobal class:**

```
public class PosicionGlobal {

public int x;
public int y;

public PosicionGlobal(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Comment: what is `pintar()` here?

Comment: it is paint in english

Comment: Pintar means 'to paint' in spanish

Comment: override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()` and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in the overridden method.

Comment: What does `Juego` extend from?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Answer (score 0):

You need to be overriding paint() not pintar()..

change

`public void pintar(Graphics g) {`

to

`@Override public void paint(Graphics g) {`

and make sure you call `super.paint(g);`

Comment: Sorry i am new to this, how do i call it?

Comment: That's rather contextual, assuming that the OP is using a Swing container, the preferred method to perform custom painting in is `paintComponent`, if it's a top level container, then the preferred method is not to paint directly to a top level container and instead use a Swing component and override it's `paintComponent` method